# Failing to format regex correctly to locate and then parse out paragraph from text document between regex1 & regex2 using python

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am trying to scrape the content between the line starting with 2) and the line starting with 3)

I have managed to iterate through the document, but I'm drawing a blank as to how to get the script to begin storing the document's contents between line 2) and line 3).

Eventually, I want to be able to harvest the variable device names "SWTEST6" & "SWTEST7" from the example, but it's not there yet.

PYTHON SCRIPT SNIPPET

```
def eat_txt(filename):
    line2 = re.search('2\)*Section 2 .*?.')
    line3 = re.search('3\)*Section 3 .*?:')

    txt = Document(filename)
    pCount = 0

    for blob in doc.paragraphs:

        if line2 in blob[pCount].text:
            for line in doc.paragraphs:
                print(doc.paragraphs)
                pCount=+1
                if line3 in doc.paragraphs:
                    break
```

SOURCE DOCUMENT

```
 2) Section 2 - Here be the SWTEST6 & SWTEST7 reboot sequence. Do much stuff.


 valid command
 !
 valid command
 !
 valid command
 !
 ! *** Comments go here ***
 !
 valid command
 !
 ! *** Comments go here ***
 !
 ! *** Comments go here ***

 3) Section 3 - Do not forget the SWTEST6 & SWTEST7 Restore Sequence and stuff:
```

Comment: `Document(filename)`? what is that, what are you parsing?

Comment: Hey @Dalvenjia - You are correct. I have answered this question below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to figure out this question and wanted to share the results. It isn't the most elegant, but it works like a charm.

The code iterates thru the document, locates the first search string, scrapes 2 hostnames (and converts them to ip addresses) from the first search string, then begins scraping lines of the document (while ignoring lines beginning with !), until it finishes upon locating the second search string.

```
def eat_txt(filename):
     line2 = 'INITIAL SEARCH STRING GOES HERE'
     line3 = 'TERMINATING SEARCH STRING GOES HERE'
     doc = Document(filename)
     paragraphCount = 0
     hostnames = []
     ipaddrs = []
     commands = []
     reading_lines = False

     for paragraph in doc.paragraphs:
         if(reading_lines):
             if(re.search(line3, paragraph.text)):
                 reading_lines = False
             else:
                 if not str.startswith(paragraph.text, '!') and paragraph.text.strip():
                    commands.append(paragraph.text)       
         elif(re.search(line2, paragraph.text)):
             reading_lines = True
             results2 = (re.search(line2, paragraph.text))
             words2 = results2.group(0).split(' ')
             hostnames.append(words2[6])
             ipaddrs.append(socket.gethostbyname(words2[6]))
             hostnames.append(words2[8])
             ipaddrs.append(socket.gethostbyname(words2[8]))
```